# Online tool to create text animation for iMovie import

Tags: software-recommendation

I am looking for an online tool to create simple text animations, to import in iMovie.

Concretely, I want to animate an intro title consisting of moving individual test string as well as simple objects like a square/line.

Comment: What about all the title animations that already exist in iMovie?

Comment: @Danielillo Doesn't do the job, you can't tell it to move a title from position x,y to another specific location.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up animating text with Apple Keynote (setting transitions to automatic) and then exporting to a 1080p .m4v movie which I could import into iMovie.